# Replacing Binary function in a Shared Object with a custom One (Under MIPSEL)

Tags: mips, embedded-linux, shared-objects, objdump

I'm trying to break inside a device of mine which has a MIPSEL core (Little endian MIPS). I mainly want to do that because the software that came on it is kinda broken and doesn't works as intended (and the manufacturer won't help me out because i don't buy thousands of units monthly).

This device has a telnet console and i have already a firmware upgrade which modifies a Shared Object (a .so file) which has relocatable code. There's one function i know is called on that .so when i access a certain feature of this device and i've already done a binary to modify /etc/passwd so i can telnet in (this can be done after i manually flash my custom firmware myself).

I've already "objdump" both files and have the dissasembly of both.

My question is:

How can i replace a given function from the original library with my custom one so i can run my code on the box? I know objcopy can work, but its kinda difficult to get documentation on it to achieve this.

What i want to do is kind like a virus, although i don't want to distribute it nor break into other's peoples devices (btw, this device i'm talking about is VERY rare).

**UPDATE**

I manually merged the binaries, copying my custom function "binarily" and then changing the relocation literals by hand. I took care to only use external functions that were already linked to the original shared object. However, i locked myself out from the device because i modified a function that is (strangely) used on device startup and the main binary which has the weakness that let me update it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own shared library containing that function(s) and override the included one using LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: That wouldn't work because i don't have shell access to the device.

Comment: How about using setenv/putenv in C to set LD_PRELOAD followed by execvp?  .... But if you could do that I guess you could install a shell.

Comment: Exactly... the problem isn't executing certain functionality, but how to get it running by piggybacking the already working binary. Anyways, i screwed my device and i'm locked out with a nice telnetable brick. Guess i need to find another faulty device to test my hack on.